# Automatic generate a parent category when adding a new node

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a content type Artist and a content type Songs. Each artist has a number of songs. I want to be able when I add a new song to assign it to the artist that it belongs and then have a view of the songs from a specific artist. I don't want to do a seperate term in taxonomy for every artist I add. Can this be automatically? ex. When I add an artist, and then I add a song I want to be able to assign this new song to the new artist without me having to manually add a new taxonomy term for the artist and then assign this song to this taxonomy term...

I want my paths to look like this.
ex: artist/songallery  ----> artist/songname

Hope I made myself clear, 
thank you in advance.

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/references ?

Comment: References wont provide the path structure that I want. Also with references I have to create a separate view for every artist I create in order to group his songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have content types a)Songs b)Artist

Create a node reference field with artist, in Songs content type. So when you add a new song you can you can select the artist belongs to that. I hope no need of taxonomy.

You can create two page displays in view by selecting necessary fields and give the appropriate path as you wish.

Hope this may help you!

Comment: OK but in the views what I actually need is a dynamic display of songs grouped by an artist, so when I click an artist I get a group of songs assigned to this artist. But can I do this with one view and how or I have to create separate view for each artist ?

Comment: I hope you can achieve this with views argument and node reference nid.                                                   Create a view to display list of songs, and another one with artist. Link the artist name field to songs view page display by passing nid. In the songs view use it as argument

Comment: What about book? would you suggest I try it?

Comment: Do you mean drupal's book module , From documentation "A book is a set of pages tied together in a hierarchical sequence, perhaps with chapters, sections, subsections, and so on. You can use books for manuals, site resource guides, Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs), or whatever you'd like." I think it is not suit your current needs well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to create taxonomy term based on Artist node title. This can help too: http://steindom.com/articles/creating-vocabularies-and-taxonomy-terms-programmatically-drupal-7